# Why generic tell me that propery doesnt exist

Tags: typescript

In one file I have next code

```
function test<T extends {}>(arg:T):any {
  return arg.name
}
```

in another I have next code

```
interface IItem  {
    name: string
}

console.log(test<IItem>({name:'3'}))
```

Why do I get an error when I try to call the name property of the args object?
Declaring the interface in a file with a test function is not an option

Comment: Why wouldn't you? `name` isn't part of the `test` definition, you could call it with *anything*: `test<{foo: string}>({ foo: "bar" })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're extending `{}` which might not have `name` property. It might not have any properties at all.

You could do this:

```
function test<T extends { name: string }>(arg: T): any {
// function test<T extends IItem>(arg: T): any {
    return arg.name
}
```